# Finding the transaction pattern using mahout

Tags: java, pattern-matching, sequence, mahout

I am trying to build something like a pattern recognizer using mahout. Its like if a user comes to buy something in my ecommerce store so based on his previous transaction pattern. I want to suggest him products in relation with the current purchase.

Suppose if the user previous transaction shows that whenever user buys brown bread he had went for jam and milk, and when user buys white bread he opts for bread and juice. So these preferences should generate dynamically according to the bread choice user makes in his future transaction.

I have read that we can use most-similar-items to get the preference item in this case, but I am unsure how can we implement it here.
Also how much parallel frequent pattern mining algorithm fits in here?

I guess this is something like sequence mining, is mahout the best framework to implement it?